# Checkbox checked event not firing in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hi in my form(adminentitylist.xaml) file contains the code is below

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iWatch.Administration"  
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:iWatch.UILibrary;assembly=UILibrary" 
                 xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
                 xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
                 xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
                 xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:iWatch.UILibrary;assembly=UILibrary"
                 x:Class="AdminEntityList">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="AddImgBtnTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Image Name="Normal" Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/Add.png" Opacity="1.0" Height="18" Width="18"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DelImgBtnTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Image Name="Normal" Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Images/Delete.png" Opacity="1.0" Height="18" Width="18"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AdminEntityList}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
        <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="Office2007Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AdminEntityList}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <StackPanel Name="StpFilter" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="FilterCriteriaArea" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding FilterCriteriaArea}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                           <StackPanel Name="StpCountry" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" >
                                <Label  Content="Select Country" Name="lblCountry" Style="{StaticResource lblNormal}" Margin="10,0,5,7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <ComboBox Name="cbCountry"  Width="170" Style="{StaticResource ddlNormal}"  SelectedValue="{Binding CountryKey,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,2,10,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Button Content="Filter" Name="btnFilter" Width="70" Height="23" Margin="0,0,10,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>                          
                          </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="actinact" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">
                                <CheckBox Name="chkactive" Height="18" Content="Active" Checked="chkactive_Checked"></CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox Name="chkinactive" Height="18" Content="In-Active"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="StpAddDel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
                                <Button Name="BtnAdd"  Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource AddImgBtnTemplate}" />
                                <Button Name="BtnDel" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource DelImgBtnTemplate}" />
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel Name="AMLDP">
                            <dxg:GridControl Name="genericGrid" AutoPopulateColumns="true"  ShowBorder="False"  
                         DesignTimeDataSourceRowCount="50"  DataSource="{Binding}"
                          Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsManipulationEnabled="True" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="CPCEGridTheme">
                                <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="CPCEGridTheme" Source="/UILibrary;component/Themes/Default/Styles/DataGrid/CPCEGridTheme.xaml" />
                                </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                        <dxg:TableView x:Name="tblGeneric" MultiSelectMode="Row" AllowGrouping="True" ClipToBounds="True"  AutoWidth="True" 
                                        ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowHorizontalLines="True" ShowVerticalLines="False" AllowMoveColumnToDropArea="False" AllowDrop="False"                                                                                                  
                                        IsGroupPanelMenuEnabled="False"  AllowEditing="False" NavigationStyle="Cell" Margin="0" 
                                        GroupRowStyle="{StaticResource OddEvenRowStyle}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" AllowHorizontalScrollingVirtualization="True" 
                                        RowStyle="{StaticResource OddEvenRowStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource FocusedCellStyle}">
                                        <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmView" IsVisible="False"  Content="View" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.View}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmEdit" IsVisible="True"  Content="Edit" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.Edit}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmMIQ" IsVisible="False"  Content="Manage Interview Questions" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.ManageInterviewQuestions}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmActivate" IsVisible="False" Content="Activate" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.Activate}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmCopyInterviewType" IsVisible="False" Content="Copy Interview Type" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.CopyInterviewType}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmAssignInvGroup" IsVisible="False" Content="Assign Investigative Group" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.AssignInvestigativeGroup}" />
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="ctmCopySelected" IsVisible="False" Content="Copy From Selected" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.CopyInterviewTemplate}" />
                                        </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
                                    </dxg:TableView>
                                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:GridControl.CommandBindings>
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdEdit" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.Edit}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdView" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.View}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdMIQ" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.ManageInterviewQuestions}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdActivate" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.Activate}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdCopyInterviewType" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.CopyInterviewType}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdAssignInvestigativeGroup" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.AssignInvestigativeGroup}" />
                                    <CommandBinding x:Name="cmdCopySelected" Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.CopyInterviewTemplate}" />

                                </dxg:GridControl.CommandBindings>
                            </dxg:GridControl>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

in the above code i created the checkbox checked event `Checked="chkactive_Checked"`

```
private void chkactive_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

but the event is not firing and i am getting an error is

> Error 14  'AdminEntityList' does not contain a definition for
>   'chkactive_Checked' and no extension method 'chkactive_Checked'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'AdminEntityList' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

please help me with is problem...

Comment: Make the method protected or public.

Comment: i tried with public and protected but it won't work..

Comment: Appears that event hander is not wired up.  It in not in the right code behind.  Right click the xaml and navigate to handler.  Or right click and create handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckboxCheckedCommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" Command="{Binding checkedCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel vm { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand checkedCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        checkedCommand = new CheckedCommand(this);
    }

    public void CheckedHandler()
    {
        //todo - implement your handler
    }
}
```

And of course the Checked Unchecked command:

```
public class CheckedCommand : ICommand
{
    private ViewModel _vm = null;
    public CheckedCommand(ViewModel _viewModel)
    {
        _vm = _viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.CheckedHandler();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more details, maybe a parameter which has to be sent from the view and received by the handler..

I see this as an easy and normal flow for MVVM. You have some instance/static method issue right there.. try the above approach, in my opinion is cleared and helps you decouple the things.

Oh, i forgot to say, `Command="{Binding checkedCommand}"` , is both applicable for `Checked` and `Unchecked` events.

**Update 1**

This can be your codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChanged)));


    private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //textbox.ScrollToEnd(); //An object reference is required for the non-static field.

        MainWindow localWindow = (MainWindow)obj;
        Console.WriteLine(localWindow.TestString);
    }

    public string TestString { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestString = "test";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
 }
```

And you CheckBox definition is this now:

```
<CheckBox Content="Case Sensitive" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

You basically define that DependencyProperty with the name IsChecked. Each time you check or uncheck it, the callback method defined there will be called. And may see an example on how to access an instance field from that static method. Good luck!

Comment: here we didn't implement in a MVVM pattern so pls help with normal solution

Comment: @trinadh try to define that command in your codebehind or define DependencyProperty and handle the callback method, when the value changes.